# Top degree de Rham cohomology determines an orientation

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M^n$ be a smooth, compact, orientable, connected manifold. We know then that $H^n_{dR}(M^n)\simeq \mathbb{R}$ by the map $[\omega]\mapsto \int_{M^n} \omega$. I was wondering if, given an orientation on $H^n_{dR}(M^n)$, there was a way to get an orientation on $M^n$?

Essentially, given a basis element $[\omega]\in H^n_{dR}(M^n)$ (so essentially a nonzero element of the cohomology), are we able to find a representative of this class which is an orientation form (everywhere nonvanishing)?

Any ideas?

Edit: The basic idea I had was a proof by contradiction: if for every $p\in M$, there is a representative of $[\omega]$ which vanishes at $p$. I would want to show that $\int_{M^n}\omega=0$. To do this, we would want to choose, in every coordinate neighborhood, a clever representative of $[\omega]$ which is zero on that neighborhood and sum up. Here's where I'm stuck.

Edit 2: Bott and Tu may have a sort of proof involving Poincare Duality (on pg. 87) which is a bit above my level. See also [theorem 3 here](https://books.google.com/books?id=0lExjG4DPJoC&pg=PA958&lpg=PA958&dq=orientation%20class%20de%20rham%20cohomology&source=bl&ots=csI7H0DQc4&sig=_U2RRe_oq3kJoKwS3vb_flgjNPM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tkJQVcnsIdOsyAS3wYGQDg&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=orientation%20class%20de%20rham%20cohomology&f=false) (the reference is to Bott and Tu).

Comment: Do you still assume that it is orientable? (Also, in the statement $M$ should also be connected).

Comment: Yes you still assume $M$ is orientable (and yes $M$ should be connected). I'm just trying to determine when given an orientation on $H^n(M^n)$, can we find an orientation on $M$? For reference, this is problem 17-8(a) in Lee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you know already that $M$ is orientable, then there is $\eta$ a nowhere zero $n$-form on $M$. Let

$C = \int_M \eta \in \mathbb R$.

Now for any $[\omega] \in H^n(M)$, consider $D:= \int_M \omega$. This is nonzero. Then $[\frac{D}{C} \eta] = [\omega]$ as

$$\int_M \frac DC \eta = D = \int_M \omega . $$

Note that $\frac DC \eta$ is nowhere vanishing (thus an orientation).

Comment: Yes, I was actually just about to make this comment. I guess I was just overthinking this a bit. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can always construct a non vanishing volume form, e.g. by choosing a Riemannian metric. Call this  $\eta$. Since $H^n_{dR}(M)$ is a one-dimensional vector space, any nonzero class $[\omega]$ is a multiple of $[\eta]$, say, $[\omega] = c[\eta]$, $c\neq 0$. So $[\omega] = [c\eta]$ and you have a nowhere vanishing representative of $[\omega]$.